# How can I determine the scale factor of a pantograph from the ratio of the arms?

Tags: geometry, transformation, transformational-geometry

I know this is probably simple but I just can't see it.

How can I determine the scale factor of a [pantograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantograph) from the ratio of the arms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale factor is the ratio $$\frac{\text{distance from the fixed point to the drawing point}}{\text{distance from the fixed point to the tracing point}}.$$
The mechanics of the device serve to keep that ratio constant as the mechanism is rotated, expanded, and/or contracted.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/linkages/1pantograph.html) breaks down the triangles pretty well.